# Relation among $L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^d)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ be the linear space consists of $L^p$-integrable functions on $\mathbb{R}^d$ for $1\le p \le \infty$. Are there any relation among these spaces?

Comment: This *must* be a duplicate. However, the short answer is no.

Comment: What do you mean by "relation"? What parameter are you varying ($p$ or $d$)?

Comment: Maybe http://math.stackexchange.com/q/66029/ and  http://math.stackexchange.com/q/170271/ answer your question?

Answer (score 5):

A simple observation, which apparently was not mentioned in either of the aforementioned threads.

If $p\le q\le r$, then $L^p\cap L^r\subset L^q\subset L^p+L^r$. This holds on any measure space, including $\mathbb R^d$.

Proof is based on the decomposition $f=f_S+f_L$ where $f_S=f\chi_{\{|f|\le 1\}}$ and $f_L=f\chi_{\{|f|>1\}}$. Indeed, $|f_S|^r\le |f_S|^q\le |f_S|^p$ and $|f_L|^p\le |f_L|^q\le |f_L|^r$ pointwise. Therefore, $f\in L^q$ implies that $f_S\in L^r$ and $f_L\in L^p$, proving the second inclusion. Proof of the first inclusion is left as an exercise.

Comment: See also [this Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_space) for additional information.