# $L^p$ and $L^q$ spaces do not include each other.

Tags: real-analysis

According to the answer at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170271/how-do-the-lp-spaces-lie-in-each-other) question, the following statement should be true.

Let $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a measure space without atoms and such that $\mu(X)=\infty$. Then, $L^p(\mu)$ and $L^q(\mu)$ do not contain each other.

Where can I find a proof of this assertion?

Comment: In order for this to be true, you'll also want to say that $\mu(X)$ is infinite...

Comment: Loved you in Mamma Mia

Comment: I guess that a way of proving this (with the additional hypothesis $\mu(X)=\infty$, thanks @Micah) is to show that a measurable function $F\colon X\to \mathbb{R}$ exists such that $$\mu(F^{-1}(A))=\mathcal{L}^1(A),$$for all Borel subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$. For something related to this, see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/31962/8157) and espectially [this answer by Byron Schmuland](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/31967/8157)[...]

Comment: @micah : Thanks.

Comment: Once this is done, it will suffice to take a function $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R})$ such that $f\notin L^q(\mathbb{R})$ and pull it back via $F$. By the change of variable formula we will have $f\circ F \in L^p(X),\ f\circ F \notin L^q(X)$. In an analogous way you disprove the opposite inclusion.